# How to get report_count from subreport in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a sub report in my main report .

I need to hide a text if sub report returns no rows.

I tried to get the number of records of subreport adding a new variable in main report and setting it as destination variable in `return values` property of `subreport(for rount_count)`, but when I run the main report, the value of variable is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To count the record's in subreport

1. **Define a variable** in main report

   ```
   <variable name="subReportCount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
   ```
2. When calling subreport set the **return parameter** to you variable

   ```
   <subreport>
       <reportElement x="100" y="20" width="400" height="20" uuid="a7a89ebb-54d4-4b6e-8c9f-c107e8a40bbb"/>
       <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[... your datasource ...]]></dataSourceExpression>
       <returnValue subreportVariable="REPORT_COUNT" toVariable="subReportCount"/>
       <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Your_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
   ```

This variable can now be used in a `textField`, however you need to be careful since the `textField` need's to be evaluate at the correct time (after subreport has been executed).

The property on the `textField` is [evaluationTime](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html)

Example

```
<textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="###0">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="300" y="60" width="200" height="20" uuid="125aa2d0-3d4e-4377-bed1-b4531c9142c9"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{subReportCount}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**Evaluation time**:

> **Auto** Evaluation time indicating that each variable participating in
>   the expression should be evaluated at a time decided by the engine.
>   **Band** The element will be evaluated at band end.
>  
>   **Column** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each column is filled.
>   **Group** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each group break.
>   **Master** Used for elements that are evaluated at the moment the master report ends.
>   **Now** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated at the exact moment in the filling process when it is encountered.
>   **Page** A constant specifying that an expression should be evaluated after each page is filled. 
>   **Report** A constant specifying that an expression should be  evaluated at the end of the filling process.

In general when using subreport

- if it is in detail band and is repeated on datasource set
  `evalutationTime="Band"`
- if it's present only one set `evalutationTime="Report"`

Comment: This doesnt seem to work when trying with printWhenExpression for textfield.

Comment: @Maxrunner The example is with a textField, maybe post another question that you show an [mcve], you can reference this question.