# Hide text field if subreport is empty

Tags: java, jasper-reports, reporting

I am creating a report in `Jasper` with four parts. Each part consists of a text field as the header and a subreport. The subreport can be empty. If it is empty it is hidden using *Remove Line When Blank*. This works so far. Now, the corresponding header text field should be hidden too if the subreport is hidden.

I have tried many things but couldn't come up with a solution.
E.g. using *Print When Expression*: `new Boolean ($P{otherField}.read() != -1)`. This never showed the header.

As well I tried to hide the header in my Java program but couldn't find an appropriate API command. I guess `getBands()[x].getChildren()[y]` lead me to the right header but I couldn't hide it there.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I finally could solve it by using the following expression under "Print When Expression" in the header:

```
($P{SUBR}!=null)
```

where

> $P{SUBR}

is the expression of the subreport.

Comment: No, sorry. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code any more.

Answer (score 6):

You should put the header text **inside** the subreport in for example a `title` band

**In subreport**

```xml
<title>
    <band height="38">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4b8ece47-1608-4d08-bc0b-e6b73bcf8346"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["TITLE"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
```

Make sure you do not have the attribute [whenNoDataType](http://apidocs.dynamicreports.org/net/sf/dynamicreports/report/constant/WhenNoDataType.html) on `jasperReport` tag, so it uses default value `NoPages`

If the subreport has no records the attribute `whenNoDataType=NoPages` (default) will ensure that nothing is returned and you will not see the title.

If you need it outside of subreport (for some strange reason) pass record count from subreport back to main report and use a text field with `printWhenExpression` and `evalutationTime="Report"`

Check out this for some additional details on how to pass back report count.

[How to get report_count from subreport in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679789/ireports-report-count-from-subreport/34680623#34680623)

Comment: You could need report count out of the subreport(s) in case where you have common header for multiple subreports and you need to show/hide header depending if any of subreports has data or all of them are empty. So its valid requirement.