# Increment variable Each time subreport is displayed

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to use a variable that is incremented each time a sub-report is displayed.

I created a variable that is called INDEX and I I used the following expression : new Integer($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()+1), but it's not working at all.

Comment: I think REPORT_COUNT is a defined variable for jasper reports and provides the count of all the records returned by the query.  You likely need to define your own variable.  See https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/514827/row-count for an example.

Comment: You can check this [How to get report_count from subreport in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34679789/5292302), instead of returning record count from subreport, return 1

Comment: `I would like to use a variable that is incremented each time a sub-report is displayed.` - Your question is unclear

Comment: Can you please post your jrxml file here?