# jasper report detect if datail band or subreport is present in current page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm developing a report with jasper.

The main report has several subreports.

Only one of these subreport has a fixed text with a note number, something like this.

```
my text<sup>(2)</sup>
```

In main report I must print the footnote, but only in all the pages in which the text with the note is present.

An image to better explain:

[image]

- Is there something that permit to detect if a subreport is present in the current page?
- Or something that permit to detect if a detail band is present in the current page?
- Or something that permit to detect if a particular text will be printed in current page?
- Or other strategy to handle this particular situation?

Comment: Just an idea: maybe you could do some trickery with variables. From subreport return number of records and print the footnote if it is greater than 0 and then somehow reset the variable.

Comment: it seems a good strategy, found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679789/how-to-get-report-count-from-subreport-in-ireport for return value from subreport and this https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-variables for understanding variable management. I'll try and post solution if it will work...

Answer (score 1):

. Create Variable in main report 'subReportCount'
  Type = Integer, default 0
  Reset Type = 'Page'

. Place this variable (hidden) somewhere after Subreport

. Create variable 'SubVar' in subreport , expression == $V{REPORT_COUNT}

. In main, go to subreport properties -> Edit return Values - > 
  Set From Varible= SubVar , To Variable=subReportCount,  Calculation type = Sum

. Page Footer Print When Expression =  $V{subReportCount} > 0

This may work if you are trying if subreport is printed atleast once in page.

Comment: Hi Pals, I deleted my solution since it does not work properly, I'm trying yours, but still I have the footnote only in the very last page, not every page with the subreport. I did everything described, I think... I placed the subReportCount variable just after subreport (same detail band), and set false in print-when to set it hidden. any suggestions? thx in advance

Comment: Hi Falco, added answer with xml samples, this should work

Answer (score 0):

Does not matter if you place subreport variable in report or not.
I tried on my local , its working for similar situation

**Variable in Main report**

```
<variable name="subReportCount" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page" incrementType="Page" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{subReportCount}.equals( null ) ? 0 : $V{subReportCount}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

**Return Value for the subreport**

```
<returnValue subreportVariable="SubVar" toVariable="subReportCount"/>
```

**Print when expression for Footer element, in my case I am showing Page number**

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{subReportCount} > 0]]></printWhenExpression>
```

This should work , if not please share your jrxml and sample data.
Good Luck!